# Create table syntax TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, create-table

I have a problem in understanding the `Create Table` syntax as shown in the MSDN.

I guess that `[]` means that sth is optional `|` - a different way - so

```
CREATE TABLE 
    [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name
```

means that you can actually use:

```
1.CREATE table table_name
2.CREATE table database_name.schema_name.table_name
4.Create table database_name.table_name
3.Create table schema_name.table_name
```

but what about {} or ()

```
CREATE TABLE 
    [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name 
    [ AS FileTable ]
    ( {   <column_definition> 
        | <computed_column_definition> 
        | <column_set_definition> 
        | [ <table_constraint> ] 
        | [ <table_index> ] 
          [ ,...n ] } 
          [ PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ( system_start_time_column_name 
        , system_end_time_column_name ) ]
      )
    [ ON { partition_scheme_name ( partition_column_name ) 
           | filegroup 
           | "default" } ] 
    [ { TEXTIMAGE_ON { filegroup | "default" } ] 
    [ FILESTREAM_ON { partition_scheme_name 
           | filegroup 
           | "default" } ]
    [ WITH ( <table_option> [ ,...n ] ) ]
[ ; ]
```

?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx

Comment: ^^^^-- seems like a valid answer to me not just a comment.  Though a snipit for {} in answer would be helpful in case link breaks. _...{ } (braces)
Required syntax items. Do not type the braces...._

Comment: You're confused about the dots. They are not as optional as you think, e.g. `database_name..table_name` requires two dots.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should check **[`Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)**:

```
| (vertical bar)  Separates syntax items enclosed in brackets or braces. 
                  You can use only one of the items.
[ ] (brackets)    Optional syntax items. Do not type the brackets.
{ } (braces)      Required syntax items. Do not type the braces.
```

Now, as for creating table you could use:

1. `CREATE TABLE table_name`
2. `CREATE TABLE database_name..table_name`
3. `CREATE TABLE database_name.schema_name.table_name`
4. `CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name`

So your `Create table database_name.table_name` is incorrect. You have to use the second example. When you pass `..` the table will be created inside default schema (most likely `dbo`).

---

As for second question how to read MSDN documentation.
Probably the best way is visual way:

[image]